# Apache http server allow, deny

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-server-2008, tomcat

I am using apache http server 2.4.4 for load balancing purpose along with tomcat 7.0.

I have hosted 2 applications under my tomcat for e.g. app1 and app2.

What I want to achieve is for app1 I want to allow only certain ips from intranet to have access on it.

I added following code to my httpd.conf file.

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\scm"
<Directory "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\app1">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from some_ip
</Directory>
```

Still I am not able to restrict the access. I have enabled the module mod_authz_host. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from some_ip
```

to just allow some_ip access to the service.

However Order, Deny and Allow are now deprecated and you might want to try

```
Require host <host_name>
```

or

```
Require ip <ip_address>
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html